# Holding down the spacebar sometimes returns Hangul in xev

Tags: keyboard, debugging

I recently decided to try Emacs. One of the things I found extremely frustrating about the software was that most of the time when I held down the spacebar, I would only get one space character inserted, and a message saying

`<Hangul> is undefined`

in the echo area. Pressing space once worked fine, and I could achieve multiple space characters by repeatedly pressing the spacebar, but holding down the spacebar did not work as expected. I went to Google to troubleshoot, but aside from [this thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51877/hangul-is-undefined-error-on-space-key-press) I couldn't find much information about it. I did luck onto the solution that hitting numlock seemed to fix the issue, however I needed to do that every time I opened Emacs (and perhaps every time I opened a new buffer -- I didn't play around with it too much.)

I opened up xev, and found that holding down the spacebar mostly produced space characters, as expected, however there were time it produced Hangul. Here is some sample output

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0x6c4, subw 0x0, time 2848166447, (-197,490), root:(767,510),
    state 0x0, keycode 65 (keysym 0x20, space), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (20) " "
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (20) " "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0x6c4, subw 0x0, time 2848166463, (-197,490), root:(767,510),
    state 0x0, keycode 130 (keysym 0xff31, Hangul), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0x6c4, subw 0x0, time 2848166511, (-197,490), root:(767,510),
    state 0x0, keycode 130 (keysym 0xff31, Hangul), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0x6c4, subw 0x0, time 2848166567, (-197,490), root:(767,510),
    state 0x0, keycode 65 (keysym 0x20, space), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (20) " "
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

It was hard to reproduce this error, and I could not tell anything that I was doing differently when it happened, however whenever I did see that error it seemed to follow this Keypress Keypress Keyrelease Keyrelease pattern.

I used the command `xkbcomp $DISPLAY my_keymap.xkb`, and I've [uploaded the file to github](https://github.com/dargski/keyboard/blob/master/my_keymap.xkb) in case it is helpful. Hangul is defined there, but I still don't understand how it's being triggered.

Some additional information that I think might be helpful:

- I am using a qwerty keyboard
- I am using Linux Mint 19.2
- Though apparently this is a system wide problem, since it's being detected by xev, I have not noticed this cause any weird behavior in applications that I am running with the exception of Emacs. If I had not run Emacs, I would probably not know about this.
- The output of `setxkbmap -query` is

  rules:      evdev
  model:      pc105
  layout:     us

Any help resolving this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested this with another keyboard? Might be good to rule out hardware.

Comment: I think 111 is correct, it looks like a hardware issue. Test it with `showkey` in the virtual console and report back if two different keycodes are returned for each space bar press.

Comment: @Quasímodo Running showkey, I am, occasionally, getting two keycodes for a spacebar press (and release): 57 and 122. Mostly it's just 57. But sometimes I get 122 as well. I will see if I can find another keyboard to try this out with. Could this potentially be a driver issue?

Comment: It may be, it may not. What if you remap hangul to space with Xmodmap?

Comment: @Quasímodo It works as it should be 75% of the time, but the other 25% of the time a spacebar press and release will enter two space characters or a spacebar press and hold will enter two spaces and nothing else.

Comment: @111---

You were right, I bought a new (wired) keyboard and this fixed the issue.